# MVC4 Action method AutoMap actionfilter fails to convert the view model to domain model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

so, I've seen this working on a previous project in MVC3, so wondering if a) i've screwed it up, or b) MVC4 is doing something different (can't see it would be).

I have a model bound Razor view which submits to a controller action method (as is the way with MVC)

post action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoMap(typeof(MyViewModel), typeof(MyDomainObj))]
public void PostAction(MyDomainObj obj)
{... etc.. etc..
```

The action filter eventually does something like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
```

NOTE: In Jimmy Bogard's example he used OnActionExecuted which I also tried..

The key issue I'm having is that at the pint where we get the "model" variable from the context, it's null.  If I look at the filterContext.ActionParameters whilst debugging I can see a MyDomainObj instance!! which appears to (because it happens to have a prop name in common with the MyViewModel type) have been mapped from my form data!

So.. yes if I had MyViewModel type as the parameter to this method, then the param would be properly populated from the submitted form.  But.  I don't want to do that, I want to (and have done before based on JB's succinct how-to) converted the view model to domain model as part of the action executed/ing and then been able to just hit save on my domain model.

Summary - why is my ViewData.Model null on the post action filter?

Comment: @Jimmy Bogard's sample from memory does a transform on the result. You're working on the inputs, which is tied up in Model Binding. I'd have a read of some materials on that subject (in the book but also do a broader search). Finally, I'd remark that it doesnt smell like a good idea, both in general and as you've described it. Model Binding is powerful and complex enough without you introducing another overlapping concept.

Comment: Thanks yeah you're totally correct, it's a different thing.  The way i have by "Get" for these methods (displaying the view) is:
[AutoMapGet(typeof(int), typeof(MyViewModel)]
public ActionResult GetAction(MyViewModel vm)

This works really well as I interpret the "int" (id) and then just map from int->domain mod->view mod using my mappers and entity resolvers. So setting my post to be:
public ActionResult PostAction(MyViewModel vm) // not really called PostAction of course

Would duplicate the Get method signature which is why i wanted Get to be view model and Post to be domain model

Answer (score 0):

Jimmmy also has/had a couple of ideas on how to implement post actions, along with another guy Matt Honeycutt who shares his view on how to do posts.  I also believe Jimmy has gone in the direction of using explicit mapping in his get requests instead of attributes, as it can be hard to inject any extra code you need after mapping.

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/22/cleaning-up-posts-in-asp-net-mvc/

http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Cleaning-up-POSTs-in-ASPNET-MVC-the-Fail-Tracker-Way.aspx

For a post you really want a couple of things imo, the original Entity and the Form Data.  You could load the entity like you do for the GET request and do normal model binding to get the form data (remember you can accept a different model for post backs than you spit out in your view) then make the changes in the action.

Of course this would require using AutoMapper in your action, which you seem to be trying to avoid.  But unless you write a custom model binder then you're not going to magically get the formdata in a model as the built in one looks at the action paramters to figure out what to bind.  For this reason i'd recommend not using a domain model as a parameter for an action, as it may fill out fields that you don't wish it to.

I've also seen Jimmy using a ModelBinder to do something similar to your AutoMapGet, which may be another alternative method, but I'm guessing you've seen that post.

My standard post takes Matt's approach, moving the validation out into a global attribute so it can't be forgotten (there are some downsides to this) then accepting a new view model explicity for the form data, then I explicity load the entity, use automapper to update it and call save.  Most the actions only end up being about 5 lines long.

I do avoid using the static methods on AutoMapper and pass a IMapper in via constructor injection.  This allows me to make it a bit more testable if I really need to, however the methods are normally so simple the tests don't add all that much value.